# How do I handle notification before it shows alert in background ?

Tags: ios, notifications

so I have this "mute chatroom" feature in my app.
If a chatroom is muted, notification data from that chatroom contains a "mute = 1"
like the following,

```
AnyHashable("aps"): {
"content-available" = 1;
alert = "Android @qwer: Gggggggg";
badge = 8;
sound = default;},
 AnyHashable("custom"): {
a =     {
    comment = 423;
    event = 133;
    mute = 1;
};
}
```

and when I receive that notification, I decide weather to show alert/sound according to mute boolean

it works fine when I received a notification when app is in foreground

it's something like :

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,  willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler  completionHandler: @escaping (_ options:   UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {  let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

    guard let data = userInfo["custom"] as? [String: Any] else { return }

    guard let additional = data["a"] as? [String: Any] else {
        print ("no addi")
        return }

    let mute = additional["mute"] as? NSNumber

    if mute == 1 {

        completionHandler([ .badge])

    } else if mute == 0 {

        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])

    }}
```

But things get tricky when app is in background,

when I received a notification when app is in background,

this method

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
```

is called, and it immediately shows a notification alert.

So how am I suppose to mute chatroom (not showing alert and mute sound) when App is in background...

Much appreciated!!!

Comment: You should not set the alert or sound keys in the push, but rather generate a local notification in response to the silent push

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to achieve this.

If your `chatroom` is `mute` then your `server` already knows, because server is sending the `push notification` with the flag `mute : 1`

So, Backend has to check, If the `mute` value is `true` then don't add the `alert` & `sound` keywords in the `push payload`. Even app is in background / foreground this will work.

**Sample payload :**

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "content-available" : 1,
        "badge" : 8
    }
    //Custom data here.
}
```

Comment: hey thanks, I will ask my backend to try removing those two keyword

Answer (score 0):

you have to implement one web service which accept boolean for application status.
when your app is in background you can call this web service with boolean true.
and for server side, when this boolean is true , then no need to send notification from backend.